# Is there easy way to get list of function declarations/signatures from .h files?

Tags: c++, c

I can run `something.h` through `cpp` and it's going to do a lot of expansions (well, mostly, it doesn't seem to work exactly the same way as compiler does), but it still leaves a lot of cruft like `#lines`, extra spacing etc.

Is there any easy way to just get list of declared functions and types/names of their arguments and return values in a reasonably automated way?

Comment: Eclipse (and any other descent IDE I guess) has a nice "Outline" view.

Comment: If doxygen does that, I have no idea how. Or how to get that kind of information from Eclipse or other IDE.

Comment: Have you looked into clang and the Python bindings to libclang? Here's an example of what you can do: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang

Comment: you may try gcc-xml - it suppose to convert C/C++ code to XML where you have better chances... check this out: http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html

Comment: Whatever you do, don't try to write your own parser that "works for our cases". C and even more C++ have an extremely complex syntax (actually for C++ it's impossible to completely check the syntax without a full compile). I've been using libclang for such purposes with great success :)